# Old guy can't figure out how to approve answer

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, answers-as-comments

I posted my first question to Stack Overflow and received two replies. I clicked on the link in the provided e-mail and the question, and two responses, were shown.

I decided to accept one of the responses as my answer..

According to the help pages, there should be some indicators next to the replies: a way to vote the answer up and a check mark so I can accept the answer. Both of my answers do not have any such indicators. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24375963/436282)? I don't see any answers there at all.

Comment: It looks like you got two *comments* on [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375963/reset-visualstudio-publishing-configuration-to-default), but not actual answers. Answers will show up lower down, and bigger, but you don't have any yet.

Comment: Sometimes a comment will provide enough of an answer that it solves your problem. When that happens to me, I usually indicate that in a comment of my own to the poster, and ask them if they wouldn't mind converting their comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I didn;t realize the difference between comments and "answers."